# MS Access Selecting Related Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, relationship

I have 2 tables with a many-to-any relationship. For the example we will call the tables "Guys" and Girls" There is a junction table that contains the related primary keys...who has dated who.

If I want to find all the girls that Guy 1 has dated, I do a select on the junction table selecting all girls with guys.ID. This give me a RecordSet. Now to find the names of the girls, I need to select from the girls table a row using the key from each RecordSet row.

Isn't there an easier way? Since I've defined the relationships in Access I would think that there must be a way to build a single query. How do I do that?

Comment: Since you've defined the relationships in Access you should be able to use the Query Design tool to write the inner joins for you automatically: IIRC one way is to open the 'Show Table', double-click to add the tables, choose the columns to show and you're done. This is one of the main features of [Microsoft QBE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Query_by_Example) and the only reason to define Relationships in the first place (referential integrity aside).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT girls.name 
FROM (guys 
INNER JOIN junct ON guys.guyID = junct.guyID) 
INNER JOIN girls ON junct.girlID = girls.girlID 
WHERE guys.guyID = [whatever id you're looking for]
```

Comment: @Papa Dilbert Welcome to JOIN country, where SQL starts to really get useful. :) Please comment if you need more explanation of how and why this works.

Comment: Yeah, been a while since I used Access...I edited the parenthesis and accepted the changes from pheedbaq

Comment: Still not right, you need to move the one after guys to before guys.

Comment: yup, fixed according to Remou